# Firebase Set key of the root Id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just wonder how to set the root id with a key of my own instead of the Push() key that gets generated inside the while loop at the top..

```
  -Waypoint  
    -RootID <-- This key
      -Points
```

....................

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, Object> pointHolder = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 LinkedHashMap<String, Object> waypointHolder = new LinkedHashMap<>();

 waypointsUrl = Constants.FIREBASE_URL + "/users/" + mUserId + "/waypoints";
        mainRef = new Firebase(waypointsUrl);
```

.................

**UPDATED CODE**

```
            while (isFirstTime) {
                // Generates root id for date
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();
                mLastUpdateTime = dateFormat.format(date);

                // Generates root id
                 mainRefKey = mainRef.push();

                isFirstTime = false;
            }


            // Generates new id for point
            Firebase wayRef1 = mainRefKey.push();
            String pointKey = wayRef1.getKey();


            // Create Waypoint > Point >  put lat and lon
            LinkedHashMap<String, Object> latLng = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
            latLng.put("latitude", 123);
            latLng.put("longitude", 123);


            // Puts lat and lon  ** under a Point Key **
            pointHolder.put(pointKey, latLng);


            // Waypoint > POINT (contains multiple points)
            waypointHolder.put("points", pointHolder);
            waypointHolder.put("timeStamp", "24/3-2016");
            waypointHolder.put("travelType", "travel");


            // ROOT ID > Waypoint
            mainRefKey.updateChildren(waypointHolder);
        }
    });
```

Picture of the desired structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend checking out the [docs on saving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html) and reading through the [api docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/)

Change your loop to do the following:

```
while (isFirstTime) {
  // Generates root id for date
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  Date date = new Date();
  mLastUpdateTime = dateFormat.format(date);

  // Generates root id
  mainRefKey = mainRef.child(mLastUpdateTime);


  isFirstTime = false;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. What is the someIdYouWant. Guess it is the root id but what is the current id then?

Comment: did this to get it to work: `mainRef.child(mLastUpdateTime).setValue(waypointHolder);` at the bottom.

Comment: I see now that it adds a pushed key together with my own key, where the pushed key is always the same and gets overwritten

Comment: But your posted code add the key to the point but i need it to the key that holds the point

Comment: Added a picture of the desired solution. But atm it adds -KICxoNHLX0BkonnPcNY as key instead of the date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112507/discussion-between-grant-and-rasmus-rajje-josefsson).